# Linq Select First Active Record in a Set

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to return the most recent revision of a document that is not in a cancelled status. However, if all the revision of the document are cancelled, it should still return the most revision in the cancelled status.

Data looks something like:

`ID |  Name  | Rev | Status
00 | Manual | 000 | Active
00 | Manual | 001 | Active
00 | Manual | 002 | Active
00 | Manual | 003 | Active
00 | Manual | 004 | Active //return this one`

`ID |  Name   | Rev | Status
01 | Manual2 | 000 | Active
01 | Manual2 | 001 | Active
01 | Manual2 | 002 | Active
01 | Manual2 | 003 | Active //return this one
01 | Manual2 | 004 | Cancel`

`ID |  Name   | Rev | Status
02 | Manual3 | 000 | Cancel
02 | Manual3 | 001 | Cancel
02 | Manual3 | 002 | Cancel
02 | Manual3 | 003 | Cancel
02 | Manual3 | 004 | Cancel //return this one`

I can group and sort the records easily. I can also filter our records with a cancelled status, but in the case of the 3rd data set, all documents are in cancelled status and I get an exception.

```
List<Records> r = records
    .GroupBy(a => a.ID)
    .Select(b => new Record
            {
                ID = b.Key,
                Name = b.First().Name,
                Rev = b.OrderByDescending(o => o.Rev)
                       .First(x=> x.status != "Cancel").Rev
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: why do you want to use a group by to find an element inside a collection?

Comment: ah i get it now, you want a query that gets you all distinct manuals satisfying the conditions. Im on it sir :)

Comment: @SharpBarb You're almost there, you can add subsequent ordering using `ThenBy`.  I've left an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there with what you have, you can use `ThenBy` after an `OrderBy` to add subsequent ordering:

```
List<Records> r = records
    .GroupBy(a => a.ID)
    .Select(b => new Record
            {
                ID = b.Key,
                Name = b.First().Name,
                Rev = b.OrderBy(o => o.status == "Cancel")
                       .ThenByDescending(o => o.Rev)
                       .First().Rev
        }).ToList();
```

NOTE: In this example I've ordered on `status == "Cancel"` as `false < true`.

---

**EDIT**

Based on the comments section requirement for extra statuses: you could create a function to convert the status into a numeric rank:

```
public int GetStatusRank(string status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case "active":
            return 0;
        case "endorsed"
            return 1;
        case "cancelled":
            return 2;
        //etc...
        default:
            return int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

You could then use this in your `OrderBy`:

`...b.OrderBy(o => GetStatusRank(o.status))`

Comment: This works given the two statuses given in the example dataset, but what if there were several additional statuses? e.g. Need to return `active` or `endorsed` or `validated` but omit `cancel` and `premilinary`.

Comment: You would just add more ThenBy calls to satisfy your statuses/conditions in the correct order. If it's more complicated than that and necessary, you should specify it as part of the question.

Comment: @SharpBarb - Adding those extra statuses is no problem for this approach.  Ideally, each status would have a numeric priority/order property that you could order by rather than the `status == "cancel"` example above. Having this numeric `order` property would enable you to easily manage and work with the available statuses.

Answer (score 1):

The following Query first orders the Items by `Status` and `Rev`. Then the `group by` picks every `ID` once. `distinctRecord.First()` returns the topmost item of that group, hence the ordering.

```
var query =
    from record in records
    orderby record.Status ascending, // Active before Cancel ('A' is alphabetically before 'C')
        record.Rev descending // highest revision first
    group record by record.ID
    into distinctRecord
    select distinctRecord.First();
var r = query.ToList();
```

The cool thing about this is, that you won't need to create a new instance of `Record`. Instead it brings back the actual Object from your Collection.

---

As you require to create new Instances of `Record` and not use references to the ones in the collection. You can do It like I've also explained in my comment:

```
var query =
    from record in records
    orderby record.Status ascending, // Active before Cancel ('A' is alphabetically before 'C')
        record.Rev descending // highest revision first
    group record by record.ID
    into distinctRecord
    select new Record { 
        ID = distinctRecord.Key,
        Name = distinctRecord.First().Name,
        Rev = distinctRecord.First().Rev,
        Status = distinctRecord.First().Status
    };
var r = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I did not this this would work at first. The document set in my actual application includes several different statuses. It turns out the only one I care about starts with an 'A' so this method worked! Also, I did need to create a new instance of 'Record' for unrelated reasons.

Comment: well you cqn modify the ordering to your needs. and you can alaways replace the select at the end with `select new Record { ID = distinctRecord.Key, Name = distinctrecord.First().Name, Rev = distinctRecord.First().Rev, Status = distinctRecord.First().Status }`. In Fact that was how I first wrote my answer until i realized, that it wasnt a requirement to create new instances.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.First(x=> x.status != "Cancel" || x.status == "Cancel")
```

Comment: the expression is alaways going to return true.. this can't work

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Records> r = records
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Status != "Cancel")
                .ThenBy(r => r.Rev).ToList();
```

after (r=>r.Rev) you can Sorting with anything else what you need. Just use .ThenBy(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

- Create an anonymous object with the Revision object (Active or Cancel)
- Create your colllection of Record using the Rev property.

  ```
  var r = records.GroupBy(x => new {x.Id, x.Name})
                 .Select(x => new {
                     ID = x.Key.ID,
                     Name = x.Key.Name,
                     RevObj = x.OrderBy(y => y.Rev).LastOrDefault(y => y.Status != "Cancel") ??
                              x.OrderBy(y => y.Rev).Last(y => y.Status == "Cancel")
                 })
                 .ToArray()
                 .Select(x => new Record() {
                     ID = x.ID,
                     Name = x.Name,
                     Rev = x.RevObj.Rev
                 })
                 .ToList();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I would use reducing based on *Aggregate*-method:

```
    var resul = list
        .GroupBy(
            k => k.ID,
            (key, groups) =>
                groups.Aggregate((accumulatedItem, item) =>
                {
                    if (accumulatedItem.Status == item.Status)
                    {
                        return string.Compare(accumulatedItem.Rev, item.Rev) >= 0
                            ? accumulatedItem
                            : item;
                    }

                    return accumulatedItem.Status == "Active"
                        ? accumulatedItem
                        : item;
                })
            )
        .ToArray();

    var list = new[] {
        new Record("00", "Manual", "000","Active"),
        new Record("00", "Manual", "001","Active"),
        new Record("00", "Manual", "002","Active"),
        new Record("00", "Manual", "003","Active"),
        new Record("00", "Manual", "004","Active"),
        new Record("01", "Manual2", "000", "Active"),
        new Record("01", "Manual2", "001", "Active"),
        new Record("01", "Manual2", "002", "Active"),
        new Record("01", "Manual2", "003", "Active"),
        new Record("01", "Manual2", "004", "Cancel"),
        new Record("02", "Manual3", "000", "Cancel"),
        new Record("02", "Manual3", "001", "Cancel"),
        new Record("02", "Manual3", "002", "Cancel"),
        new Record("02", "Manual3", "003", "Cancel"),
        new Record("02", "Manual3", "004", "Cancel")
        };

public class Record
{
    public Record(string id, string name, string rev, string status)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Rev = rev;
        Status = status;
    }
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Rev { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```